# Execute script from i3 config

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, i3, xbindkeys, macro

**Question:**

I'm using i3-wm and I have Mod3 working as a hotkey. I have the following in `./config/i3/config`:

```
#This command works
  bindsym Mod3+f exec "firefox" 

#This doesn't work nor do my other scripts
  bindsym Mod3+w exec "openBrowser"
```

Both of these commands work fine when I run them from bash but only the 'firefox' command runs with the hotkey. Running my own script doesn't work.

**Additional Details:**

openBrowser is a script in `/opt/bin/` which is in my path. Also tried doing:

```
#This command works
  bindsym Mod3+f exec /opt/bin/openBrowser
```

I've also tried other scripts none of which work when invoked by i3. Thus I've determined it's not an issue with the script.

I also noticed when I'm in bash if I do Mod3+w my cursor blinks, where as if I do Mod3+[any unset key] the key writes it's value to the screen. So it seems i3 is at least trying to run the function.

Comment: You have `openBrowser` in your config but also tried `/opt/bin/openbrowser`. So how the file is actually called? Case matters. Also, do you have any relative paths in that script? i3 runs it from other directory than your script is located in. This could also be a reason. Try to start the script from the directory where i3 config is located.

Comment: Just a typo the second time, I used openBrowser which is the correct naming.

Comment: Try to execute it from the console in a folder where i3 config is located. It should reveal errors if any

Comment: @ddnomad as I mentioned in the text both commands work fine when I run them from bash.

Comment: Can you add a source of a script to your question? I guess you're trying to open a Tor browser using an i3 shortcut?

Comment: @ddnomad question updated; no just picking a random site, but I also want to make it easy to switch to chromium or another browser while keeping the same startup settings.

Comment: I tried the same but with Mod4+f and it works (except the fact that it only opens the firefox). My `xmodmap` has no set mod3, did you set it by hand?

Comment: @ddnomad yes I replaced caps lock with hyper-key using this answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151046/16792 (and it's working fine for Mod3+f )

Comment: Try to remove doublequotes from the script name. i3 throws me an error if I add them. So kinda like that: `bindsym Mod3+f exec openBrowser`. If it won't work out try the absolute path.

Comment: @ddnomad thx but no luck with either changes. It's weird that you're getting an error and I'm not though. When/where does the error show? I tried Mod3+r exec "reboot -n" and that works.

Comment: It throws the red bar at the top of the screen stating that the command can't be executed. It's indeed weird.

Comment: Do your scripts have at least 755 permissions? i3 probably has its own user that the desktop runs under and uses to call commands. Since you are able to run the script normally, and system-installed packages work through the shortcut, it sounds like a permissions issue to me.

Comment: @Thegs yes permissions of 755

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride Do you know where your `i3` output is going to? I'd have a look at that and see if there is any error printed when you try that key combination. What kind of scripts is this? (Which scripting language?)

Comment: @Thegs here `i3` does not run under a separate user, and I doubt such a thing would be practical — after all, the window manager needs to start applications for the user which is using it, and it would be harder/more complicated to do so if it were running under a separate, unrelated user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I attempted to duplicate the issue you describe. What I found is that I had two i3 config files existing at the same time. `~/.config/i3/config` and `~/.i3/config`.

In my case, editing `~/.config/i3/config` had no effect because it seems that `~/.i3/config` trumps it.

It's a long shot, but see if maybe you have more than one config file, and possibly you are editing the wrong one.

Comment: This is not the case for me because I added the `exec "firefox"` command in the same file and it loaded no problem. So I'm sure the config file loads.

Comment: Maybe try this:

bindsym Mod3+f exec set > /tmp/set.out

and have a look at the PATH, to see if it is what you expect.

Comment: nvm it was the case that I had 2 config files like you. I was able to figure some other stuff out with `Mod3+f exec set > /tmp/set.out`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `exec` command starts an application by passing the command you specify to a shell. This implies that your programs will be searched in your `$PATH`. The default `$PATH` usually does not include `/opt/bin`, for example my is:

```
andreatsh@debian:~ 11:28 > echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Try adding `/opt/bin` to your path, put in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt
```

I did some tests and this solves the problem for me. Now:

```
bindsym Mod3+w exec somescript
bindsym Mod3+w exec /opt/bin/somescript
```

have the same behavior and the script works.

Comment: thanks for trying but I already addressed the possibility of a path issue in my question text.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride The default config has `bindsym Mod3+w layout tabbed`, maybe there is a conflict caused by `binsym Mod3+w exec "openBrowser"`, or this last `bindsym` is overwritten by the first?

Comment: you mean it has 'bindsym Mod+w layout tabbed' it doesn't reference mod3, and mod refers to windows or alt key. I also tried other letters so I can rule that out.

Comment: Have you tried to enable i3 logging? Maybe you could get some useful error messages, or it could be a bug of your release version.